# Markdown Mode: Is there a way to display changes on-the-fly?

Tags: markdown

I found two ways to display preview of the `markdown` files in `markdown` mode. One is <kbd>C-c C-c p</kbd> which requires a parser (currently I use `pandoc`) to preview using browser. The other is  <kbd>C-c C-c l</kbd> which display preview using `eww` in `emacs buffer`. However, none of them display changes in a "real-time" way.

For the first one, I have to strike <kbd>C-c C-c p</kbd> every time after edited. It will open a new time in my browser each time which is very annoying.

If I use  <kbd>C-c C-c l</kbd> I can use  <kbd>C-c C-c e</kbd> or simply save file to update changes but still not convenient.

More over, I found some subtle differences between these two commands' outputs. Which one is the real one?

Comment: I hope this [link](https://github.com/shime/emacs-livedown) can help, never tried it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Markdown#Live_preview_as_you_type

#### Flymd

https://github.com/mola-T/flymd This may be the simplest. Install this package with package.el (on MELPA), call the mode with `M-x flymd-flyit`. It opens a browser window.

#### Impatient-mode

https://github.com/skeeto/impatient-mode This one needs a bit more setup (explained in wikemacs) but it works out of the box for html live rendering.

Answer (score 0):

[Skewer](https://github.com/skeeto/skewer-mode) looks really nice. Not under active dev though.

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer to make it a self-contained post.  We generally discourage link-only answers -- in part to avoid treasure hunts, and in part to avoid link-rot.